# Android Webview, trying to save as image file only seems to store a blank image

Tags: android, webview

I must be doing something wrong here with saving the image or something, as when I save it as a png, its a blank white image. When I save it as a JPEG, it's a blank black image.

The webview loads in my application after about 1 second.

```
    .....
        webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview_1);

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                //Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                Bitmap b = getBitmapFromWebView(webView);
                Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
                view.draw(c);

                try {
                    FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("test.png", Context.MODE_APPEND);
                    //fos = new FileOutputStream( "/sdcard/"  + "page.jpg" );
                    if ( fos != null ) {
                        b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, fos );
                        fos.close();
                    }
                }
                catch( Exception e ) {
                    System.out.println("-----error--"+e);
                }
            }
        });

        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/World_display.html");



....
    public Bitmap getBitmapFromWebView(WebView wv) {
        webView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        webView.buildDrawingCache(true);
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(wv.getDrawingCache());
        webView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
        return bitmap;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the webview isn't rendered until sometime after onPageFinished. All of this code being in my onCreate was saving a blank image because the webview hadn't been rendered yet.

Ended up doing this as a separate method outside onCreate:

```
    public Bitmap getBitmapFromWebView(View v) {
    webView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    webView.buildDrawingCache(true);
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getDrawingCache());
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("test.png", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        //fos = new FileOutputStream( "/sdcard/"  + "page.jpg" );
        if (fos != null) {
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, fos);
            fos.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("-----error--" + e);
    }
    return bitmap;
}
```

And calling this method from within a "submit" button onclick in the onCreate.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
public static  Bitmap getBitmapfromView(View v) {
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getWidth(), v.getHeight(),
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    v.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}
```